# PHP - LightHouse - ID Scalar size not enough

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I have a DB Table with a big int primary key. When my primary key is too large like 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' i get always this same value on lighthouse graphql query: 2147483647

Is there a way to declare the size of my ID? Like `id:ID! BigInt`

Comment: Do you really need a big int primary key? I doubt you do...

Comment: @B001ᛦ Thank you for your comment. 
I don't have a choice. 
The database is already being used this way for years.

Comment: @b001ᛦ Larave's default primary key when creating tables is bigint 
`$table->id();` -> `Alias of $table->bigIncrements('id')` -> Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED BIGINT (primary key) equivalent column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it done by adding:

`protected $keyType = 'bigint';`

on the laravel model class.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution

Answer (score 0):

Cast you your column to string in your query, and use [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) on the PHP side.